# Backbone collection and view sorting

Tags: backbone.js, coffeescript

I set 'comparator' method in my collection so that I can sort list in collection.
but it doesn't effect to view.

**'/api/note/getList'**, it returns (and it called when collection be initialized by view)

```
[{"id":22,"name":"Test2","isPublic":1},{"id":11,"name":"Test1","isPublic":1},{"id":33,"name":"Test3","isPublic":1}]
```

This is my collection,

```
define [
    'models/Note'
],
(Note) ->
    class NoteCollection extends Backbone.Collection

        model : Note
        url : '/api/note/getList'

        initialize: () =>
            _.bindAll @
            @.on 'sort', @onSort

        comparator : (item) ->
            id = item.get 'id'
            return id * -1

        onSort: () =>
            @.each (model) =>
                console.log model.get 'id'
```

onSort method prints,

```
11
22
33
```

correctly, but on view, it shows

```
22
11
33
```

This is my view,

```
define [    
    'hbs!./noteCollection_tpl'
    './noteItemView'
    'collections/NoteCollection'
],
(noteCollection_tpl, noteItemView, NoteCollection) ->
    class NoteCollectionView extends Backbone.Marionette.CompositeView
        template : noteCollection_tpl
        itemView : noteItemView
        itemViewContainer : '.noteListContainer'
        className : 'noteWrap'

        initialize : (options) ->
            @collection = new NoteCollection()
```

Do I have to re-render view? if so, how can I catch the (what) event when after url be loaded and all list be into collection?

please advice what I am doing wrong.

Comment: yes you will have to rerender the view after sorting the collection. sorry i'm not good at coffeescript, but in your view's initialize, you can:  this.collection.on('sort reset', this.render, this);  this catches the events of when the collection is 'reset' (like, after fetch() is done) and when the collection is sorted.

Comment: I see. Thank you. (BTW, it is annoying job to hook that event..)

Comment: yea, backbone doesn't have data-binding in views by default. BTW, if you are using backbonejs > 1.0. using listenTo is better. eg. in your collection's initialize:  this.listenTo(this.collection, "sort reset", this.render);

Comment: BTW, `_.bindAll @` won't work with newer versions of Underscore, you must specify the method names now (http://underscorejs.org/#bindAll).

Comment: @mu is too short, Yeah, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need to render when collection be sorted.

```
initialize : (options) ->
    @collection = new NoteCollection()
    @collection.on 'sort', () =>
        @render()
```

Aww, better using '**listenTo**' because,

**When the view is destroyed, the listenTo call will automatically remove the event handler. This prevents memory leaks and zombie event listeners.**

I'v believed, using marionette will solve this zombie event listeners.

**Thanks Yurui Ray Zhang.**